# Could not find python installation

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I am using MacOs BigSur and node version v14.17.3, i am getting below error whenever i try to run my run script

It breaks at step

**ERROR [build 3/5] RUN npm ci --production &&     cp -r node_modules /tmp/prod_node_modules  &&     npm ci**

```
 > [build 3/5] RUN npm ci --production &&     cp -r node_modules /tmp/prod_node_modules  &&     npm ci:                                                           
#8 7.205                                                                                                                                                          
#8 7.205 > node-rdkafka@v2.10.1 install /app/node_modules/node-rdkafka                                                                                            
#8 7.205 > node-gyp rebuild                                                                                                                                       
#8 7.205                                                                                                                                                          
#8 7.353 gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 7.354 gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
#8 7.354 gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
#8 7.355 gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
#8 7.355 gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 7.355 gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
#8 7.355 gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 7.355 gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
#8 7.355 gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 7.355 gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 7.355 gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#8 7.356 gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
#8 7.356 gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
#8 7.356 gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
#8 7.356 gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#8 7.357 gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
#8 7.357 gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
#8 7.358 gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
#8 7.358 gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#8 7.358 gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
#8 7.358 gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
#8 7.358 gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#8 7.358 gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 7.359 gyp ERR! configure error 
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:307:47)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:271:16)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:326:5)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:338:5)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
#8 7.360 gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
#8 7.361 gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.25-linuxkit
#8 7.361 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
#8 7.361 gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/node-rdkafka
#8 7.361 gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.3
#8 7.361 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
#8 7.362 gyp ERR! not ok 
#8 7.373 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#8 7.374 npm ERR! errno 1
#8 7.379 npm ERR! node-rdkafka@v2.10.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
#8 7.379 npm ERR! Exit status 1
#8 7.379 npm ERR! 
#8 7.379 npm ERR! Failed at the node-rdkafka@v2.10.1 install script.
#8 7.379 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile

Comment: It has nothing to do with docker file, because the same docker file was able to build before i installed node-rdkafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add below lines in my dockerfile

```
RUN apk --no-cache add \
      bash \
      g++ \
      ca-certificates \
      lz4-dev \
      musl-dev \
      cyrus-sasl-dev \
      openssl-dev \
      make \
      python3

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc zlib-dev libc-dev bsd-compat-headers py-setuptools bash
```

This solved my problem, if you see the first run command it is adding the python to the docker image, similarly g++, gcc and other library.